# Как отобразить текстовый файл

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Получаю текст фетч запросом, но не записывается ответ в переменную что-бы отобразить его в компоненте

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Redirect, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { docco } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';

export default function GistsContent(props) {
  const { gistName } = useParams();
  const selectedGist = props.gistsFiles.find(item => item.filename === gistName)

  let content;
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(selectedGist.raw_url)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(data => content = data) // не записывает данные в переменную
  }, [gistName])
  


  if(!selectedGist) {
    return <Redirect to='/'/>
  }
  
  return (
    <div >
      <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" className='gistContent'  style={docco}>
        {content}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
...  
const [content,setContent] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(selectedGist.raw_url)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(data => setContent(text));
  }, [gistName])
```